# 20A Bathroom Circuit including lights/fan, add outlet for 1300w(max) bidet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Pretty sure I'm okay here

20A=2400w, 1300w bidet, ~160w fan, ~100w LED lights=~1500w which is less than 80%. Only possible hiccup is it is in a master bath with dual vanity so slight chance my partner and I will be sharing the room and they would be using a hair dryer at the same time I'm flushing.

To make life a bit easier I'd like to tap into the line in the attic prior to where the circuit first connects to the lights/outlets where there is already a junction box and run a new GFCI in parallel rather than extending from the last outlet in line in the bathroom already behind drywall that will likely require drilling through some studs.

This also leaves open the posibility to run a new dedicated circuit for this plug in the future if it ends up becoming a problem.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both items are not continual use and even if using a hair dryer while the bidet is heating it may not trip inverse time breakers will handle a brief overload without tripping, it would be similar to my granddaughters using a curling iron and a hair dryer at the same time, every now and then it trips but not enough for me to run another circuit.

Comment: No sense posting my answer because I said the same thing basically. +1